# Passing values from form to function in other class then call function in form

Tags: c#

I have a form and a class. In the form, I have a textbox and an empty label. A user is supposed to type something in the textbox then press a button. I want the textbox value and empty label to be passed to the class where I have a function that passes whatever value was in the textbox into the label, then empties the textbox again. When I type something in the textbox and click the button though, nothing happens. This is basically what I have.

Form:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Class _class;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _class = new Class();
    }

    public string TextBox
    {
        get { return TextBox1.Text; }
        set { TextBox1.Text = value; }
    }

    public string Label
    { 
        get { return Label1.Text; }
        set { Label1.Text = value; }     
    }

    private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (TextBox1.Text != string.empty)
        {
            _class.Function();
        }
        else
        {
            Something else
        }
    }
}
```

Class:

```
class Class
{
    public void Function()
    {
        using (var form = new Form1())
        {
            string TextBox = form.TextBox;
            string Label = form.Label;

            if (Label == string.Empty)
            {
                Label = TextBox;
                TextBox = string.Empty;
            }
            else
            {
                Something else
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Because `var form = **new** Form1()`. Also, `Label = "something";` does not equal `form.Label1.Text = "something";`.

Comment: Required reading: **[new operator (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/new-operator)**.  Note that you are not *passing* anything at all from the form to the class function, no matter what the title says.  If you were passing the controls, it could work.  Also, a `void` function is a contradictory notion.

Answer (score 0):

In order to modify your current Form you need to pass the object to the function, it is not correct to create a new Form every time the function is called. So I guess you are trying to do something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
private Class _class;

public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _class = new Class();
}

public string TextBox
{
    get { return TextBox1.Text; }
    set { TextBox1.Text = value; }
}

public string Label
{ 
    get { return Label1.Text; }
    set { Label1.Text = value; }     
}

private void btn1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (TextBox1.Text != string.Empty)
    {
        _class.Function(this);
    }
    else
    {
        //Something else
    }
}
```

`Class:
class Class {
public void Function(Form1 form)
{
    string TextBox = form.TextBox;
    string Label = form.Label;
    if (Label == string.Empty)
    {
        Label = TextBox;
        TextBox = string.Empty;
    }
    else
    {
        //Something else
    }
    
}`

Anyways, there are better ways to modify properties of Forms Controls. You should [take a look at PropertyBinding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.binding?view=windowsdesktop-6.0), it let you bind a property of a class with a Control Form

Comment: Now it is 2023, I'm still wondering if this is what Ibrahim was looking for